# Too much white space with \insertbox

Tags: graphics, typography

I am using \insbox instead of wrapfig in order to have text and a picture side by side in a list environment.

The problem is that by using a command like

```
\InsertBoxL{3}{example-image}
```

The picture ends up being way shrunk in the whitespace containing it. Are there any parameters I can use to correct this unwanted behaviour, or alternative solutions?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx, wrapfig}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[linkcolor=teal,colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\input{insbox}


\begin{document}
blablablablablablabla blablablablablablablab lablablablablablabla
blablablablablablablabla blablabla blablablabla blablablablablabla
\InsertBoxL{3}{\includegraphics[width=6cm]{example.png}} 
blablablablblablablablblablablablblablablablblablablablblablablablblablablablblablablablblablablabl
paaaaaaaaaaablablblablablablblablablablblablablabl
blablblablablablblablablablblablablabl
blablblablablablblablablablblablablabl
blablblablablablblablablablblablablabl
blablblablablablblablablablblablablabl
blablblablablablblablablablblablablabl
blablblablablablblablablablblablablabl
blablblablablablblablablablblablablabl
blablblablablablblablablablblablablabl
blablblablablablblablablablblablablabl
blablblablablablblablablablblablablabl
ablablblablablablblablablablblablablabl
ablablblablablablblablablablblablablabl
ablablblablablablblablablablblablablabl
ablablblablablablblablablablblablablabl
ablablblablablablblablablablblablablabl
ablablblablablablblablablablblablablabl
ablablblablablablblablablablblablablabl

\end{document}
```

Screenshot. I saved the png file with almost no borders so all of the border around it is insertBox' doing.

[image: screen]

Comment: you should provide an example that shows the problem (you can use `example-image`)  unrelated to insbox `\includegraphics[width=8cm]{bla.png}` will make an image 8cm wide, if that is shrunk too much specify a different width

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your output on which you mark which whitespace you would like to change?

Comment: I can't reproduce the result with a random example image https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ha1Co.png Can you share your `example.png` so we can check if the white space is part of the image?

Comment: Do you get the same problem if you use `\includegraphics[width=6cm]{example-image-a}`? (this image should be included in most tex distributions)

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz hmmm, no. I guess my picture was the problem all along which is crazy because I know how I saved it.